# Is it financially preferable to purchase Treasury bonds on the primary market or on the secondary market?

Tags: united-states, investing, bonds, treasury, auction

Assume a retail investor who:

- can purchase Treasury bonds on the secondary market through their broker without any [fees or markups](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/155553/5656) (e.g., via [Charles Schwab](https://www.schwab.com/fixed-income/pricing)).
- can only submit non-competitive bids when purchasing Treasury bonds on the primary market, i.e. cannot submit competitive bids (e.g., that's a limitation of the [Charles Schwab website](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/155621/5656)).

Is it financially preferable to purchase Treasury bonds on the primary market or on the secondary market?

E.g., the secondary market has a bid-ask spread, while non-competitive bids typically give sub-optimal yield-to-maturity. Let's ignore the fact that the investor may have to wait for the auction date on the primary market.

Comment: @0xFEE1DEAD no, here I'm looking at finance, not convenience. Also, there's no difference in convenience  when purchasing Treasury bonds on the primary market via one's broker.

Comment: Hypothetical questions based on unrealistic assumptions are of little interested to anybody but you.

Comment: @0xFEE1DEAD what are the unrealistic assumptions? The question describes my exact situation.

Comment: For starters, nobody, be it retail or professional investors, can transact without fees or markups, so it's a moot point.

Comment: What's "financially preferable" depends on your finances, of which we know nothing, and your priorities, of which we know nothing.

Comment: @0xFEE1DEAD The question has a link to [Charles Schwab](https://www.schwab.com/fixed-income/pricing), which shows no fees and no markups.

Comment: @littleadv financially preferable = higher yield-to-maturity. My priority = get the highest yield-to-maturity.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt then the answer is obvious: purchase the bonds that give you the highest yield to maturity. D'uh.

Comment: Is the highest yield to maturity typically obtained with noncompetitive bids on the primary market or on the secondary market?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt sorry, I didn't look at the fee schedule earlier. We don't have to assume then, given that it's a fact.

Comment: @0xFEE1DEAD depends on the broker, hence stated as an assumption.

Answer (score 1):

> non-competitive bids typically give sub-optimal yield-to-maturity

Why? You get the same market yield as everyone else, except that you're not an active bidder.

> Let's ignore the fact that the investor may have to wait for the auction date on the primary market.

You can't ignore this. The market may move between now and the auction. Also, the auction yield is unknowable ex ante.

A bird in the hand is worth two in the bush. If you like the yield you're seeing in the secondary market, go for it.

Comment: "Why? You get the same market yield as everyone else, except that you're not an active bidder." -> The low rate may be far from the high rate, e.g. https://treasurydirect.gov/instit/annceresult/press/preanre/2022/R_20220906_3.pdf  (3.460% vs. 3.100%) I believe non-competitive bids get the low rate.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt you can believe all you want, the rate is set at the auction and is the same for everyone.

Comment: "All auction awards are made at a single price, computed from the yield at which the
auction stopped." https://www.newyorkfed.org/medialibrary/media/research/current_issues/ci11-2.pdf

Comment: @littleadv  and 0x: interesting, I got confused by [What rate do non-competitive bids get at Treasury bond auctions?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/155728/5656). What does the "Allotted at High" (= 58.13%) mean then?

Comment: You're either a competitive bidder or you're not, so which one are we assuming?

Comment: @0xFEE1DEAD noncompetitive bidder. (from the question: "can only submit non-competitive bids when purchasing Treasury bonds on the primary market, i.e. cannot submit competitive bids (e.g., that's a limitation of the [Charles Schwab website](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/155621/5656)).")

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt right, so why do you worry about the high rate if it's not available to you? All non-competitive bids get the same rate. At the end of the day, the difference between buying treasuries in the primary and secondary market is likely marginal and you're better off focusing on improving your investment process than chasing basis points. Premature optimization and all that...

Comment: @0xFEE1DEAD "do you worry about the high rate if it's not available to you?" could've been available to me in secondary if competitive bidders receive higher yield than noncompetitive bidders. But thanks to you and littleadv, I've learned that's incorrect: both competitive and noncompetitive bidders receive the same yield, if filled. https://money.stackexchange.com/a/155730/5656

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt that's not what I said but I'm not going to spend my evening arguing with you.